# CTakes with Tika

Tags: scala, apache-tika, ctakes

Has anyone integrated ctakes parser with Tika , I would like to use Tika to extract text from documents and use ctakes to get annotations . I’m able to extract using Tika the text and some metadata but would like some advise / help on how to configure ctakes with Tika . Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you try the [official Tika docs](https://wiki.apache.org/tika/cTAKESParser)?

Comment: Yes, there is some information on ctakes Apache site but Need help following that . Not much information is posted

Comment: The [page has](https://wiki.apache.org/tika/cTAKESParser) lots of detail, lots of information, steps, debugging instructions etc, not sure what more you'd need!

Comment: Yes it list a lot of information which is not clear to me . It would be appreciated if you can point to me the file that the page is listing to make changes . Ctakesparser.config and xml files. Should I create a new config file and I do not see the parameters that are being mentioned to be modified in any of the files as part of ctakes !

Comment: @RData you can try using ctakes web rest module which gives you the analyzed outputs as mentions out of the box

Comment: @Gandhi thanks . But there is not rest service out of the box ? More guidance would be appreciated . Are you asking me to build a rest service for ctakes ?

Comment: @RData we have rest service implementation already in place for cTAKES. Look for cTAKES web rest module in ctakes Svn repo. It's already tested by me and recently improvised by Tim.

Comment: @Gandhi have you got cTAKES working? I have been trying to get it working for 2 weeks with no luck. could you please help me with that?

Comment: @asmgx Hi, cTAKES with rest service is integrated to cTAKES codebase already

Comment: @Gandhi if you have any steps or links that we be of a great help for myself and others here - thanks .

Comment: @Gandhi Would be great if you can link a manual of how to integrate cTAKES APIs in any code.

Comment: @asmgx request to check this module - https://github.com/apache/ctakes/tree/trunk/ctakes-web-rest